# Add children from array

Tags: arrays, swift, sprite-kit, parent-child

I've been trying to learn swift for a few days now, and all tutorials I've found had had a specified number of `SKNodes`. I'm trying to programmatically add new instances to an array `nodeList` and add them to the scene, because I want each of them to execute some code periodically. This is my current version of code for adding more objects:

```
if (last_created < 0)  {

    //Some other code here

    for i in 0...3 {
        self.nodeList.append(self.backObject);

        var x_current = CGFloat(Float(arc4random())/4294967296.0 * Float(x_range) + Float(x_min));
        var y_current = CGFloat(Float(y_min) - Float(y_range));

        self.nodeList[self.nodeList.count-1].position = CGPoint(x: x_current, y: y_current);
        self.addChild(self.nodeList[self.nodeList.count-1]);
    }
}
```

Attempt to execute this raises an exception:

```
Attemped to add a SKNode which already has a parent
```

I assume that every item in my `nodeList` array is seen as the same object, rather than separate instances. However, I don't know how to fix the problem. How should I have done this?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding self.backObject to the array multiple times, so it is being added to the scene more than once, causing the error. You should create a new instance of the node within the loop and add that to the array.